# Getting "Cannot resolve symbol RobotActivity" with QiSDK

Tags: android, pepper

I am trying to get my `pepper robot` to perform some simple speech tasks. I can follow the tutorial all the way up to "Creating a robot application". It seems like step 2 where you "robotify" the application is not working correctly. It creates a file called `robotsdk.xml` in the assets/robot directory but did not do any other modifications as mentioned in the tutorial. When I copy the example code at the bottom of the tutorial into `MainActivity`.java I get the error in the title.

here's a link to the tutorial.

https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch1_gettingstarted/starting_project.html

I have tried following the tutorial on a Windows 10 machine *and* a Linux machine and I get the same problem.

I am able to connect to the robot and slightly move the limbs around using the "Connect" button in the Pepper SDK in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

The class RobotAcitivity is part of the QiSDK dependency. You have to ensure that your build.gradle file contains the line (should happen automatically in step 2)

```
implementation 'com.aldebaran:qisdk:1.6.7'
```

Also make sure that gradle downloaded all dependencies successfully before running the application.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get it working by downloading and opening this git repo with Android Studio. https://github.com/aldebaran/qisdk-tutorials

Answer (score 0):

In the built.gradle, please add

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://android.aldebaran.com/sdk/maven'
    }
}
```

}